# SQL ACCESS максимально приближенное число

Tags: sql, access

Доброго времени суток. 
У меня есть таблица с двумя полями Датой и числом.
Необходимо найти максимально приближенную дату к введенному значению.

Comment: Как определить, насколько приближены дата и число? Без примера как-то не очень понятно.

Comment: В заголовке "максимально приближенное число", в теле вопроса "максимально приближенная дата". Вы уж определитесь и постарайтесь поконкретнее описать вопрос, экстрасенсы на летних каникулах.

Comment: Спасибо большое что откликнулись. Уже сам решил задачу. Простите что не достаточно конкретно задал вопрос. Торопился. Еще раз благодарю за ответы.